# need explaination for how swing method paint() works?

Tags: java, swing, paint

I have a simple paint application, I'm trying to understand how paint method works, the method has an arguments of type Graphics,

```
public void paint( Graphics g ) { 
    g.fillOval(x, y,20, 20);
}
```

my question is from where is this Graphic object g coming from?

this is the full code:

```
public class Painter extends JFrame {

private int x = -10, y = -10;

public Painter()
{
    super( "Simple Painter" );setSize( 500, 500 );setVisible( true );
    addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseWatcher());
}

@Override
public void paint( Graphics g ) { 
    g.fillOval(x, y,20, 20);
}

private class MyMouseWatcher extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent event ){
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        repaint();
    }
}

public static void main( String args[] )
{
    Painter painter = new Painter();
    painter.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing( WindowEvent event )
                {System.exit( 0 );}
            }/* end inner class*/ );
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for an explanation on how painting works.

Hint, you should NOT be overriding paint() and you should NOT be doing custom painting on a JFrame.

Comment: Thank you, the application does work, I just need to know from where did we get the Graphics object.

Comment: +1 in particular take a look at [Painting in AWT/Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), which is linked from the link provided, but is easy to miss. ;)

Comment: @e.s There are a lot of good reasons why you shouldn't override paint of a top level container like JFrame and why you should be calling super.paint. Understating how painting works will stop you from making simple mistakes that will produce unexpected and unwanted side effects or performance issues

Comment: `I just need to know from where did we get the Graphics object` - you don't need to know that. All you need to know is that the method will be passed a Graphics object. It is not relevant for you how that happens. You could ask the same question about every method in the API because all methods have a method signature and the Objects all come from somewhere. `the application does work` it is more important that you learn how to do painting properly (since the code you posted is not proper) than it is to know where the Graphics object comes from.